React DataTable Component - Reset sort on third click in the column heading
I use the react-data-table-component to display all my data. The built-in sort is great but when I accidentally click on it, I would find myself refreshing the page just to reset the sorting.
I scour the API documentation, but I can't seem to find a built-in solution

Please elaborate, what do you mean when you say you "accidentally click on it" the sorting? Also what does this do to the sort that you have to reset?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@MikeLyons Hello, if a user accidentally clicks on the sorting button (the column headers) they won't have the means to go back to the default state when the table first loads.

The examples for this component load the data in a default sorted state. I assume you don't want the data sorted by default? Something about the unsorted load state of the data is desirable to you? What is determining the default sort state of the data, recency?

@MikeLyons I was asking if the API has an option for a column sort reset. I want to be able to reset the sort or undo the sort the column on the third click. Currently, the column can be clicked once for sorting ASC and a second one for DESC. I want to have a third click to remove the current sort to return the column to its first state

The short answer to your question is that this component does not support returning to a default loaded sort order and you'll have to roll your own custom behavior that stores and restores the original order of the data with a reset button or by adding the third click function to the sort heading.
